# Simple Class not working python

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

can't get a simple class example to work and i have no clue why.
why does my object have no attributes?

```
class Player(object):

    def _init_(self, name="n", hp=25):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
    def take_hit(self):
        self.hp -= 5

dude= Player()
print (dude.name)
dude.take_hit
print (dude.hp)
```

Comment: `__init__` and `dude.take_hit()`

Answer (score 3):

`__init__`, like all Python magic methods, needs to have two underscores on each side, not one.

Comment: oh thank-you so  much! darn syntax...